# Load object from RavenDB

Tags: asp.net, refactoring, ravendb

I'm trying to do some refactoring on a project. I want to replace the code between the lines and with the two commented lines above it so I can use it on another page where I need the quote object

```
        //quote.LoadActive();
        //QuoteID = quote.Id;

        //--------------------------------------------------------
        List<Quote> DBquotes = session.Query<Quote>()
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
            .ToList();

        foreach (Quote q in DBquotes)
        {
            if (q.IsActive)
            {
                QuoteID = q.Id;
                quote = session.Load<Quote>(q.Id);
            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the LoadActive() function inside the Quote class

```
    public Quote LoadActive()
    {
        List<Quote> DBquotes = session.Query<Quote>()
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
            .ToList();

        foreach (Quote q in DBquotes)
            if (q.IsActive)
                return session.Load<Quote>(q.Id);

        return new Quote();
    }
```

But I don't know how to actually update the quote object. I can't update  inside the function without doing it element by element and that's too tedious. If I try and do quote = quote.LoadActive() then it complains that quote hasn't been initialized. I'm sure there's a way to set up what I'm trying to do but I'm blanking and can't think of good keywords to google my question. I couldn't even come up with a good subject wording for this post!

EDIT: tl;dr I need to load the active quote into the 'quote' object to be used by the page. What's in between the lines works, I want to replace all with the commented lines above (or something similar).

Comment: You need to clarify your question a bit, what is it you are trying to do exactly? Return Active quotes? Update a quote? to what?

Comment: I want to load the active quote from the DB into that 'quote' object to be manipulated and used by the page

Comment: "The" active quote? You probably have many active quotes. Is quote a child collection of some parent object...we'll say customer, where as a customer can have many quotes but only 1 active at any given time?

Answer (score 0):

You're Quote object should not be responsible for accessing the database. You should be using some Data Access class or even better yet, a [Query Handler](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) to access the DB.

I think you might be a little confused as to what the code is doing. Let me try to explain.

```
  public Quote LoadActive()
    {
       //This call returns every Quote Document in the DB
       //RavenDB by default will only return a Max of 128 w/out doing paging

        List<Quote> DBquotes = session.Query<Quote>()
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
            .ToList();

     //This doesn't make any sense. You're saying the first quote that is active, 
     //make another expensive DB call and return the same object.
     //I still don't know what you want to do, but you already have the quote object 
     //why would you go to the DB and get something that you already have?

        foreach (Quote q in DBquotes)
            if (q.IsActive)
                return session.Load<Quote>(q.Id);//Unnecessary, you have the Quote already
               //return q;

        return new Quote(); //if there's no active quotes just return an Empty Quote Object
    }
```

Are you trying to return all Active Quotes from the DB?
You can do this

```
var activeQuotes = session.Query<Quote>()
                   .Where(x => x.IsActive == true)
                   .ToList();//Remember, RavenDB's safe by default feature 
                             //will only return 128 records, you have to
                             //implement paging
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to just return the first IsActive quote (which is what it looks like you want to do from your code) you can simply do:

```
    public Quote LoadActive()
    {
        return session.Query<Quote>()
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
    }
```

Edit based on comment:
This will allow you to accomplish what you want by

```
QuoteId = quote.LoadActive().Id;
```

Comment: that is a better way to write that, I agree. However my primary concern is in the other code snippet. I want to update the quote object there with the quote returned from the query. Is there a way to write my function so that the only line needed in the first snippet is "quote.LoadActive()"

Comment: i updated my answer to reflect how you can do what you asked for.

Comment: `quote.LoadActive().Id` doesn't make any sense. `LoadActive()` will return the same object every time (depending how it decides to order the list) despite whatever the quote object actually is. `GetActiveQuotes(customer.Id)` makes more sense.